# concatenate list of sentence into one in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i try to concatenate or join multiple list of sentences into 1, but failed:
for for example i have this dataframe df (2 rows):

```
    text
=====================
    ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
    " Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."]
    ["Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.",
    "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt."]
```

the desired result is:

```
text
==================================
["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.]
[Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.]
```

i try using:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.join(' ')
```

but it separate word into character and the sentence aren't joined

Comment: What is `print (df['text'].head(5).to_dict())` ?

Comment: still not work, the result stil give separated text

Comment: I ask for it because it seems data related problem, so from sample data hard to realise where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the letters for every row but you want to concatenate all the rows.
Try this:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame()
df["text"] = ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
" Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."]
df['text'] = " ".join(df['text'])
print(df['text'][0])
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete code then.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you have to use such form:

```
new_string = "".join(df['text'].tolist())
```

Then you can create a new dataframe:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[new_string], columns=['text'])
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'text':[['a','boy','is','noob']]})

df['text']=df['text'].str.join(' ')
```

input:

```
df['text']
Out[14]: 
0    [a, boy, is, noob]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

output:

```
df['text']
Out[12]: 
0    a boy is noob
```

Comment: So OP say this solution failed, why answer same solution like posted in question?

Comment: @jezrael If the solution is failing, Then the input must be not in a structured way.
i'm showing him that the solution he's using is apt.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65406855/concatenate-list-of-sentence-into-one-in-a-dataframe#comment115636769_65406855

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the dataframe column into a list and then use str.join() to concatenate it.

```
d = {'text': ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
"Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
" Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

" ".join(list(df['text']))
```

This should produce

```
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
```

Note that the string acting as the delimiter in `" ".join()` can be changed.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Edit 1:
It seems the OP wants to concatenate the lists per row. If so, lambda function may be used.

```
d = {'text': [["text11", "text12", "text13"],
            ["text21", "text22", "text23"],
            ["text31", "text32", "text33"]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(list(x)), axis=1)
```

This should produce the following output.

```
> df['text'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(x))
0    text11 text12 text13
1    text21 text22 text23
2    text31 text32 text33
```

Comment: I'm sorry maybe my question is not clear enough, but the example i use is only 1 row, so in 1 row, it has a list of sentences. when trying your code, it joined all of the sentences in every row

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that was not clear. So do you want for each row, the list of sentences should be concatenated?

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect list concatenation per row. Please check the edited answer and confirm if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

```
df['text'] = [' '.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['text']]
```